# Setting up Marketing Cloud as an Auth. Provider

Tags: marketing-cloud, namedcredentials, auth-provider, external-services

Lately we've been integrating very tightly with Marketing Cloud, so I thought about trying to set up the `External Services` which Salesforce provides in order to do some minor actions via flows.

In order to be able to setup the `External Services` feature I first needed to setup a `Named Credential` and for that, an `Auth. Provider`.

The issue I came up with was setting up Marketing Cloud as an `Auth. Provider`. When authenticating against MC, it returns a *non-standard* JSON which instead of containing a `access_token`, it contains an `accessToken`.

[**Example:**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm)

```
{
  "accessToken": "************************",
  "expiresIn": 3600
  "refreshToken": "************************"
}
```

This makes setting up the flows slightly more complicated.

So, given this scenario, is it possible to set up Marketing Cloud as an `Auth. Provider` in Sales Cloud? In that case, what's the recommended way?